# Php foreach array index HTML modal? Use PHP variables inside modal?

Tags: php, modal-dialog

In my code I'm returning a `array` of items/designs which im previewing using `HTML` as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Once I'm clicking on a item/design a form modal will popup and offer the user some `selects` and `input` fields.

The code looks like the following:

```
<?php foreach($designs as $design): ?>
    <!-- HTML code to display designs which are returned from a PHP class -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
<div id="modal_form_vertical" class="modal fade">
    <!-- Modal HTML code -->
</div>
```

As you can see I'm storing the `modal` code outside the `foreach` loop.

Since I'm able to click different items/designs I'm not sure how to use the urls/names/ids which are returned by the index position of the array.

**Question:** How would I use the PHP `variables` which are aviable inside the `foreach` loop inside the `modal`? Do I really have to create a `modal` `foreach` design/items by placing the `modal` code inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: Have you looked into doing this with Ajax rather then building the modals in PHP?

Comment: No I didn't yet. Actually the PHP code is just previewing the items/designs, the modal itself is just HTML code yet. Since I have no clue how to use the PHP variables in there since I don't want to have a modal foreach array index in my source code. I would want to have one modal, changing their values on select of the item/design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to add the `variable` to the modal trigger button as `data attribute` against which you can fetch or retrieve the relative information from database via modalevent listener & ajax method

Modal trigger buttorn

```
<?php foreach($designs as $design): ?>
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_form_vertical" data-designid="<?php echo $variableId;?>" class="btn btn-default">Modal</button>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Modal [event listener](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) & Ajax method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal_form_vertical').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var designid = $(e.relatedTarget).data('designid'); //get the id
        alert(designid);
        var dataString = 'designid=' + designid;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/design_content.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#designcontent").html(data);
            }
        });
     });
});
```

Create `design_content.php`

```
<?php
   //Include DatabaseConnection
   //$_POST['designid'];
   //Run query
   //Fetch Data
   //Echo data to show in Modal
?>
```

Modal HTML

```
<div id="modal_form_vertical" class="modal fade">
    <!-- Modal HTML code -->
    <div id="designcontent"></div> //Here will show the data fetched via ajax.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, got it working with the help of your explanation.